# how to use webpack for html5 srcset images

Tags: html, webpack, webpack-3

In development mode i am using require for html images and compiling using webpack.

Html:

Below code is compiled using webpack and return output as normal html but how to use it for html5 srcset 2x 3x images?

```
<img src=<%=require("./images/test.png") %><!-compiled properly-->

<img src=<%=require("./images/test.png") %> srcset="images/test-2x.png 2x, images/test-3x.png 3x" class="img-fluid" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In webpack.config.js
Install srcset loader after that use the rules below.

```
 module: {
            rules: [
                   {
                    test: /\.(gif|png|jpg|svg)$/i,
                    use:[
                        {
                            loader: 'srcset-loader',
                        },
                        'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=images/',
                        'image-webpack-loader']
                  }
}
```

Html:

```
 <img src=<%=require("./images/test.png")%> srcset="<%=require("./images/test-2x.png")%> 2x ,<%=require("./images/test-3x.png")%> 3x" class="img-fluid" />
```

Now using this code webpack will optimize 2x 3x images in production mode.